# Making fraction output in mixed number format

Tags: c, arrays, loops, fractions

I made a program so when the user selects option 1 they can input a numerator and then a denominator, if they select option 2 it will print that fraction. However i want it to print the fraction in mixed form. For example if I did 20/3 it would print as 6 2/3. Any help as to how i would approach this problem?

This is my code ( hopefully easy to read (: )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Struct to hold fraction data
typedef struct fraction
{
int numerator, denom;
}fraction;


int main()
{
//Array of 100 fractions
fraction arrFraction[100];

int i = 0, j, num = 1;

//Loop till user want to stop

while (num == 1)
{
    int choice;
    printf("\nPress 1 to enter a fraction\n");
    printf("Press 2 to view stored fractions\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);


    if(choice == 1)
    {
        //Prompting user
        printf("\nEnter your fraction, numerator followed by denominator\n    ");

        //Reading values from user
        scanf("%d %d", &arrFraction[i].numerator, &arrFraction[i].denom);

        //Incrementing counter
        i++;

    }

    if (choice == 2) {

        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            //Printing fractions
            printf("\n  %d / %d \n",  arrFraction[j].numerator,     arrFraction[j].denom);
        }

    }
}//end of while loop



return(0);
}
```

Comment: Try using `%`  as in `printf("%d  %d/%d\n",  n/d,     n%d, d);`

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: And what about e.g.: `12/4` or `8/6`?

Comment: Check if the modulus is 0, and don't display the fraction.

Comment: Still: `8/6` = `1 2/6` = `1 1/3`. No full reducing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use division(/) and modulus(%) operators.

```
    printf("%d %d/%d",  
      arrFraction[j].numerator / arrFraction[j].denom , 
      arrFraction[j].numerator / arrFraction[j].denom , 
      arrFraction[j].denom
    );
```